# Detecting network connectivity/ performance degradation of aws ec2 instances with 'health check type: EC2'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, health-monitoring, automatic-failover

Many of my ec2 instances do not have an ELB. I want to do an automatic failover or at the very least have my autoscaling policies honor network connectivity issues, faulty ec2 hardware, performance degradation etc. which in turn would mark instance unhealthy. I don't want to change health check type to ELB and leave it at EC2 (because my instances don't have ELB). Could you give me pointers on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you DO have autoscaling groups. In this case, AWS WILL replace instances automatically if it detects faulty hardware or connectivity problem. No additional steps are needed from you.

Answer (score 1):

And in case, you want to extend the status checks on other parameters like threads or container queue size etc, you can implement Health evaluation based on these metrics using health heck endpoint.
I have explained this Technique in my blog https://yoursandmyideas.com/2017/08/11/detecting-server-instanceprocess-health-status/